# Error while sending and receiving sms using AT commands with c# .Net

Tags: c#

I am trying to send and receive sms using C#.Net code (using AT commands) that I got from CodeProject.

This application is working but after an hour or two, it stops working and haults, it says some times no success message was received or response received is incomplete.
 If i reconnect modem, then it again starts working.

Please let me know the better solution. I am using huwai modem.

The code is as below:

```
 public ShortMessageCollection ReadSMS(SerialPort port, string p_strCommand)
    {
        // Set up the phone and read the messages
        ShortMessageCollection messages = null;
        try
        {
            #region Execute Command
            // Check connection
            ExecCommand(port, "AT", 300, "No phone connected");
            // Use message format "Text mode"
            ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");

            // Use character set "PCCP437"
            //ExecCommand(port,"AT+CSCS=\"PCCP437\"", 300, "Failed to set character set.");
            // Select SIM storage
            ExecCommand(port, "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"", 300, "Failed to select message storage.");

            // Read the messages
            string input = ExecCommand(port, p_strCommand, 5000, "Failed to read the messages.");

            #endregion

            #region Parse messages
            messages = ParseMessages(input);
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        if (messages != null)
            return messages;
        else
            return null;
    }
public bool sendMsg(SerialPort port, string PhoneNo, string Message)
    //public static bool sendMsg(SerialPort port, string PhoneNo, string Message)
    {
        bool isSend = false;
        //clsSMS objclsSMS = new clsSMS();
        try
        {
            //03 Apr 2014 (Increased TimeOut since False is returned though the msg is sent successfully)
            //string recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT", 300, "No phone connected");
            string recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT", 1000, "No phone connected");

            //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 1000, "Failed to set message format.");
            // MessageBox.Show("1 "+recievedData);
            String command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + PhoneNo + "\"";
            //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 1000, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
           // MessageBox.Show("2 "+recievedData);
            command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";

            //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds ***** PROBLEM

            //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 5000, "Failed to send message"); //incremented to 5 seconds
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 4000, "Failed to send message"); //decreased to 4 seconds
            //MessageBox.Show("3 " + recievedData);

            if (recievedData.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
            {
                isSend = true;
            }
            else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                isSend = false;
            }


            else 
            {
                isSend = true;
            }
            return isSend;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
public string ExecCommand(SerialPort port, string command, int responseTimeout, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {

            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();

            receiveNow.Reset();

            //string str = port.ReadExisting();
            port.Write(command + "\r");

            //str = str+port.ReadExisting();// port.ReadExisting();


            string input = ReadResponse(port, responseTimeout);
            if ((input.Length == 0) || ((!input.EndsWith("\r\n> ")) && (!input.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))))
                throw new ApplicationException("No success message was received.");
            return input;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing about your device model I can only suggest that maybe there's a timeout value after which it'd close the connection, i.e. try to poll the device regularly.